# Not getting the exact result what it should give me in the Firebase query

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In the text watcher is queried like this but when any user changes the data it doesn't find that new changed data

```
TextWatcher tw = new TextWatcher() {

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(searchMainFragment);
        quickResultsList.clear();
        quickResultsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        if(!s.toString().isEmpty()){
            Log.e(TAG, "onDataChange: "+ s.toString());
            Query query =  application.getMRef().child(getString(R.string.db_user_details)).orderByChild(getString(R.string.db_displayName))
                    .startAt(s.toString().toLowerCase().trim()).endAt(s.toString().toLowerCase().trim() +"\uf8ff");
                /* query.keepSynced(true); */
                query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                            for(DataSnapshot single : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                                quickResultsAdapter.add(single.child(getString(R.string.db_displayName)).getValue().toString());
                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                        }
                    });

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        //application.getMRef().child(getString(R.string.db_user_details)).keepSynced(false);
        Log.e(TAG, "afterTextChanged: "+ " text has been changed");
    }
} ;
```

if i use keepsynced then it runs but if i dont use it doen't work. i dont want to sync this amount of data into my cache how can i resolve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `addListenerForSingleValueEvent`, the listener will read the data precisely once. That means that your `onDataChange` gets called with the current value (from the cache if available, otherwise from the server), and stop listening immediately after that.

If you want to keep listening for changes to the data, you should use `addValueEventListener`. Using this means that (like with `addListenerForSingleValueEvent`) your `onDataChange` gets called immediately with the current data, but (unlike `addListenerForSingleValueEvent`) the listener will stay active after that and your `onDataChange` will be called for later changes too.

Comment: as much the data big returned from query

Comment: is there any way not to store that data in the cache so it always call the server

Answer (score 0):

It will be better it you use this outside the block

```
Query query =  application.getMRef().child(getString(R.string.db_user_details)).orderByChild(getString(R.string.db_displayName))
                .startAt(s.toString().toLowerCase().trim()).endAt(s.toString().toLowerCase().trim() +"\uf8ff");
            /* query.keepSynced(true); */
            query.addChildEventListener (new ChildEventListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onChildAdded (@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        for(DataSnapshot single : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                            quickResultsAdapter.add(single.child(getString(R.string.db_displayName)).getValue().toString());
                        }
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        for(DataSnapshot single : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                            quickResultsAdapter.add(single.child(getString(R.string.db_displayName)).getValue().toString());
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });
```

But this will also work

```
TextWatcher tw = new TextWatcher() {
boolean isMethodCalled = false;
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(searchMainFragment);
        quickResultsList.clear();
        quickResultsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        if(!s.toString().isEmpty() && !isMethodCalled ){
            Log.e(TAG, "onDataChange: "+ s.toString());
               Query query =  application.getMRef().child(getString(R.string.db_user_details)).orderByChild(getString(R.string.db_displayName))
                .startAt(s.toString().toLowerCase().trim()).endAt(s.toString().toLowerCase().trim() +"\uf8ff");
            /* query.keepSynced(true); */
            query.addChildEventListener (new ChildEventListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onChildAdded (@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        for(DataSnapshot single : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                            quickResultsAdapter.add(single.child(getString(R.string.db_displayName)).getValue().toString());
                        }
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        for(DataSnapshot single : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                            quickResultsAdapter.add(single.child(getString(R.string.db_displayName)).getValue().toString());
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });
isMethodCalled  = true;

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        //application.getMRef().child(getString(R.string.db_user_details)).keepSynced(false);
        Log.e(TAG, "afterTextChanged: "+ " text has been changed");
    }
} ;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
TextWatcher tw = new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(searchMainFragment);
        quickResultsList.clear();
        quickResultsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        if(!s.toString().isEmpty()){
            Log.e(TAG, "onDataChange: "+ s.toString());
            Query query =  application.getMRef().child(getString(R.string.db_user_details)).orderByChild(getString(R.string.db_displayName))
                    .startAt(s.toString().toLowerCase().trim()).endAt(s.toString().toLowerCase().trim() +"\uf8ff");
            query.addChildEventListener (new ChildEventListener() {

                @Override
                public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
                    for(DataSnapshot single : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                        if(single.getKey().equals("displayName")){
                            Log.e(TAG, "onChildAdded: "+ single.getValue().toString());
                        }
                    }
                    //Log.e(TAG, "onChildAdded: "+ dataSnapshot);
                }

                @Override
                public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
                    for(DataSnapshot single : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                        try {
                            if(single.getKey().equals("displayName")){
                                Log.e(TAG, "onChildChanged: "+ single.getValue().toString());
                            }
                        }catch (NullPointerException e){
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        //application.getMRef().child(getString(R.string.db_user_details)).keepSynced(false);
        Log.e(TAG, "afterTextChanged: "+ " text has been changed");
    }
} ;
```

by using this i got my result and it is the active listener also so i don't need to worry about the sync process.